# How to stop boostrap dropdown been partly hidden underneath next table row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code:

```
<tr>
    <div class="form-group" >
      <th>
        <input type="email" value="{{email}}" class="form-control" id="email">
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="form-group" s>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" value="{{password}}" class="form-control" id="password">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="min-width: auto;">
                  <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Add</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </th>
    </div>
  </tr>
```

But the dropdown is partly hidden below the next row.
[image]
I tried all sorts of `z-index`s in various places but its no good.
Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: _I tried all sorts of z-indexs in various places but its no good._ What places? Can you share? What `z-index` did you set on what elements?

Comment: Cant share it now because I deleted them. But the main one I tried was a on `<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="min-width: auto; z-index:10;">`
Also tried a dynamic z-index on each row `<tr style="z-index: -{{id}};">`

Comment: The z-index of `dropdown-menu` needs to be higher than the z-index of `dropdown-toggle`.  Did you try adding z-index to both like that?   If that doesn't fix it then there's something else going on beyond the code you've posted here.

Comment: @sn3ll Yes I tried that as well as the groups.

Comment: Is there any other code that may affect this?

Comment: Again, there must be something else going on then.  Could you make a fiddle reproducing the problem so we can play with it?

Comment: I don't think so. It's all dynamic using handlebars.

Comment: I could post the whole page?